# PHP one line, different variables

Tags: php

I have a php file with multiple lines that are identical in all ways, except for the variable displayed in them. At the moment, there are 26 lines of code, but can be reduced to two if there's a way to repeat the static php and place the dynamic variables in their required place. I'm asking for a place I can find some documentation on the function I'm looking for, or for an example that can help me work this out.

**Some sample code:**

```
<div id="DynamicName" <?php if ( $Survival == "Online" )
{echo "class='span2 up'><div class=service><div class=name>Survival</div><h2 class=status></h2>";}
else {echo "class='span2 down'><div class=service><div class=name>Survival</div><h2 class=status></h2>";} ?></div>


<div id="DynamicName2" <?php if ( $DynamicName2 == "Online" )
{echo "class='span2 up'><div class=service><div class=name>DynamicName2</div><h2 class=status></h2>";}
else {echo "class='span2 down'><div class=service><div class=name>DynamicName2</div><h2 class=status></h2>";} ?></div>
```

This is not the full code, but is the required portion that needs to be repeated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a loop of some sort.  W3schools is a very good site to learn HTML and PHP.  Here is a good example showing you how to do loops:

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_looping.asp

```
$x = 1; 

while($x <= 5) {
** Put code here ***
$x++;
}
```

Hope this helps you get going. If you get stuck, feel free to post back or browse on here how others have done their loops.

Comment: Do you know of the way to put a dynamic variable in the code?

Comment: The best way is through using an array.  Declare the array before the loop and index it based on which index you are on.

Comment: I could give you a cookie! This is more than what I was looking for an saves me hours of manually creating 300+ php functions!

Comment: @Dooley_labs  A cookie would be nice but no problem :)